# Is there a NavigationTiming interface available on XMLHttpRequests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, google-analytics, xmlhttprequest

The `window.performance` object exposes information about performance of the last page load done by the browser, including dns lookup times among others. However, I haven't been able to find anything similar for Ajax calls.

The higher-level problem I'm trying to solve is to be able to use Google Analytics to track load times. You can set custom events and track timing on javascript, but there is currently no way of getting lookup times, and other relevant performance data. Maybe there is a way to get this information from the `XMLHttpRequest` object?

Comment: does this adds some sort of solution http://analytics.blogspot.fr/2012/04/more-ways-to-measure-your-websites.html ?

Comment: Not exactly, the `window.performance` object has much more information, like dns lookup time. The post only talks about timing you can track from the client side using Javascript.

Comment: Then you just need to look at the built in performance reports http://analytics.blogspot.fr/2012/03/measure-your-websites-performance-with.html but this is for page loads, not ajax calls...

Answer (score 4):

`window.performance.timing` -- defined in the W3C 
[NavigationTiming](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) specification, only exposes performance metrics of the root document's page load.

The W3C [ResourceTiming](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/) specification, on the other hand, exposes performance information for all of the page's resources, such as `img`, `script` and `XMLHttpRequest`.  ResourceTiming is implemented in IE10+ and is currently prefixed in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the same level of information that you get using `window.performance` I think that the ***answer is NOT***.

In the [w3.org spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) of `XMLHttpRequest` you only find a list of events, using that you could get some times, but not the same detail of network times.

Maybe you can look for something similar to [Firebug-NetPanel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel_Architecture_Review), which is using a *XPCOMInterface* [nsIHttpActivityObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpActivityObserver)